# Proving / Disproving V is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V be the set of n × n matrices such that tr(A) = 0.

(a) Prove or disprove that with the usual matrix addition and scalar multiplication, V is a vector
space.
(b) What is the dimension of the span of V ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You are looking for $\ker \operatorname{tr}$. The answers follow from this.